# Applin Evolution Items?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

While roaming around the Wild Area in Sword, I managed to get some Tart Apple... but what of Sweet Apple? Is it possible to get a Sweet Apple as well, or are these items version-exclusive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The apples are exclusive. Shield can only get Sweet Apples, and Sword can only find Tart Apples.